# What does this ERROR from the daemon mean?

Tags: monerod, daemon

> > ERROR   ringct  src/ringct/rctOps.cpp:264       ge_frombytes_vartime failed at 264

It is preceded with a date, and then a 12-digit hexadecimal number, which I wasn't sure was something personally identifiable, so I left it out.  It starts with 7bf and ends with 700.

There are occasional warnings or errors in the daemon log that are really unimportant from the node owner's perspective.  Is this one of those?  Perhaps this is from a transaction that someone broadcast from an old incompatible wallet?  It would be nice to know that this message was about someone else on the network, rather than something wrong with my build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the data inside a ringct transaction is invalid in a certain way. For instance, an previous version of ringct had the same layout, but used the data in it differently, with different assumptions, checked there, so a tx made with a wallet from that version would trigger this.

It is possibly doable to have more in depth preliminary checking, but it is unclear whether it'd require redoing part of the rct code in the preliminary check code.

Unless your daemon stops syncing, this is ignorable.